# Timer is being fired frequently in gwt which makes scrolling unresponsive when viewing it in an ipad

Tags: ipad, gwt, timer, scroll

I am using GWT 2.4.

I am using `Scheduler.get().scheduleFixedDelay(new Scheduler.RepeatingCommand()` and `Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand()` when needed.

For some reason, when I am debugging the website a timer fired event is being shown frequently even when I am in the login page(where I do nothing besides showing username and password).

Why is this happening? It is because of this, that the scrolling looks unresponsive.
Please note that I am remotely debugging the website by connecting my ipad to macbook.

Attached is a screen grab. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> a timer fired event is being shown frequently

Do you mean that the RepeatingCommand  gets executed over and over ?

As soon as you call scheduleFixedDelay, the scheduler will execute the RepeatingCommand as long as the execute() method returns true.

> I am in the login page

How about writing a log to see if the scheduled command you are talking about in the question gets invoked, even if you're not logged in ?

Comment: I have no idea if RepeatingCommand is actually invoking the timer. I don't get any information from the recorded javascript events in safari developer tools. All I am shown is a 'some-alpha-numeric-digits.cache.html' and on clicking it, its navigating to a particular line where I can see $wnd.setTimeout(g,250). AFAIK I am not setting this timeout, but somehow this timeout is being set.

Comment: Please put a log in the scheduled command. Does it shows up on each timer invocation ?

Comment: I put a log everywhere I used a scheduled command, but nothing is being logged which means that it is not the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. So forget about my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion though. Looks like I have to try different things. I'll let you know once I arrive at something.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for the delay. On each touch start I was getting all the text and applying a property like `html.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("webkitUserSelect", "none")` as part of my requirement. The data in that html is pretty big and to keep doing it on every touch start was causing a delay. Got rid of it now.